# Want to store array as value in javascript map

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a map where key is string and value is an array Like  below .How to store a array with key as string in map

```
fruits : apple,orange,pineapple
countries:usa,uk,india,australia
cities:frankfurt,berlin,moscow

var map = new Object(); 

map['fruits'] = myObj1;
map['countries'] = myObj2;
map['cities'] = myObj2;

function get(k) {
    return map[k];
}
```

Comment: Assuming `fruits`, `countries`, and `cities` were properly declared and initialized (they aren't above), the code above works. What's the problem?

Comment: so var myObj1 = ["apple", "orange", "pineapple"]; should work?

Answer (score 4):

you can use **[map() collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn479050(v=vs.94).aspx)** in javascript

```
var myObj1 =[" apple","orange","pineapple"]

var map = new Map();
map.set("fruits", myObj1);  // to set the value using key
alert(map.get("fruits"));   // to get the value
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qmnum8cf/)**

Comment: there's a certain irony in pointing at a Microsoft web page for an ES6-only feature...  Try this link instead - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Comment: If you're going to demonstrate a feature that will only work in cutting-edge browsers, you should say you're doing that.

Comment: @Alnitak Thanks for giving useful link:)

Comment: @Alnitak I can recognize the irony (although it's not all that ironic now that IE is leading the push for ES standards), but why is the MDN link preferable?

Comment: @JLRishe because it has far more information, including cross-browser compatibility  (NB: IE11's support for `Map` is actually quite poor)

Answer (score 3):

Other than creating the arrays, your code storing them in the `map` object is fine. (But see below for a much more concise version.)

Here's the corrected array initialization:

```
var fruits = ['apple', 'orange', 'pineapple'];
var countries = ['usa', 'uk', 'india', 'australia'];
var cities = ['frankfurt', 'berlin', 'moscow'];

var map = {}; // There's no reason to use `new Object()`

map['fruits'] = fruits;
map['countries'] = countries;
map['cities'] = cities;

function get(k) {
    return map[k];
}
```

These three lines:

```
map['fruits'] = fruits;
map['countries'] = countries;
map['cities'] = cities;
```

can also be written:

```
map.fruits = fruits;
map.countries = countries;
map.cities = cities;
```

But your code can be much more concise:

```
var map = {
    fruits: ['apple', 'orange', 'pineapple'],
    countries: ['usa', 'uk', 'india', 'australia'],
    cities: ['frankfurt', 'berlin', 'moscow']
};

function get(k) {
    return map[k];
}
```